# javascript set value of search box and press search button facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

when i try to set facebook search box value nothing happen,
this is the code:

```
var mySearchValue = 600;
var setSearch = window.document.getElementsByClassName('uiSearchInput')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
setSearch.value = mySearchValue;
```

this code for press search button:

```
var clickSearchButton = window.document.getElementsByClassName('uiSearchInput')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
clickSearchButton.click();
// clickSearchButton.submit();
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors reported in your browser?

Comment: i don't think it's possible .it's an iframe